# Why is "builded" an archaic variant of built, given that usually the language evolves the other way?

Tags: etymology, irregular-verbs

In one of the Nature articles related to Google n-grams site [1], as well as in the book [2], the authors describe (and quantify the rate of) the process of regularization of English irregular verbs.

The word "built" seems to have moved the other way, from regular to irregular, since I found the variant "builded" listed in a dictionary as archaic. Is there an explanation for this exceptional occurrence?

[1] https://www.nature.com/articles/nature06137
[2] [https://www.amazon.com/Uncharted-Data-Lens-Human-Culture/dp/1594487456](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594487456)

Comment: I've seen the "builded" variant in https://www.google.cz/search?q="I+have+builded+a+monument+more+lasting+than+bronze." and got curious...

Comment: By "from regular to regular" did you mean "from regular to irregular"? By the way, "dived"  -> "dove" may be another example, although "dived" is not considered archaic yet.

Comment: The English poet Swinburne used "builded" to rhyme with "gilded" in his 1860-ish poen "Dolores".

Comment: There are other verbs that have also moved the other way: *dived/dove, sneaked/snuck, dragged/drug* (although the regular past tenses are still also used for these).

Comment: @PeterShor The regular past tenses _dived, sneaked_ and _dragged_  are still regarded as standard as far as I can tell; the irregular versions are American non-standard (though I must admit that as a Brit I'm rather partial to 'snuck').

Comment: The ‘t’ verbs are a funny group. Some have the t past as an alternative to the d past, usually most common in BrE (dreamed/dreamt), some have the two in fairly equal variation (kneeled/knelt), some have only a t past (felt), some have a d past in very limited use (bent, but on bended knee). _Built_ seems to have moved from group 1 or 2 to group 3. I’m not sure I’d really call it becoming irregular as such – it’s just lost the most regular form in favour of a mostly regular one.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: In the U.S., *dove* and *snuck* are quite common, and just as acceptable as *dived* and *sneaked* (although *drug* is definitely non-standard). But they're all several centuries younger than *built*, which the OED dates back to the 15th century, so *built* has had much more time to displace the regular form completely.

Comment: And *dove* certainly appears as if it might be on its way to displacing the regular form in the U.S. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+dove%2CHe+dived%2CHe+sneaked%2CHe+snuck&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20dove%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20dived%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20sneaked%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20snuck%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @bof Also note the leftpondian *Battle Hymn of the Republic*, in the same era: *I have seen him in the watch-fires of a hundred circling camps. / They have builded Him an altar in the evening dews and damps*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Regular and Irregular, Weak and Strong

Past tenses and participles such as *built* or the British past tense *spelt, learnt, spilt* or *burnt* are orthographically irregular, but that does not make them irregular verbs in the sense the *Nature* article is using that term. There, an irregular verb is a Germanic strong verb which forms its past and participle through vowel change: *sink, sank, sunk; drive, drove driven*.

The article gives statistical underpinnings to the long-observed phenomenon that infrequently used Germanic strong verbs tend to become weak, though even common verbs such as *help* — OE *helpan, healp, holpen*, ModGer *helfen, half, geholfen* — could become weak as well.

“Irregular” in this sense also includes English verbs that became strong through analogy, such as [*strive, strove, striven*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/strive#etymonline_v_22189), like *drive*, which is becoming regular again for many speakers: *strive, strived, strived*, or *dove* as the past of *dive*, though no one ever said **diven*. And no one knows where [*dig, dug, dug*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dig#etymonline_v_8562) came from — there is no obvious cognate verb in other Germanic languages and an anology formation to *stick, stuck, stuck* seems a bit far-fetched.

A weak (regular) verb is one which forms its past and participle by means of a dental suffix (*d* or *t*) without vowel change.  A hybrid is one that does both: *think, thought, thought; bring, brought, brought*. In this sense, *build* is still a regular verb: it has no vowel change and it ends in a dental consonant. It is still irregular in the sense that its past and participle cannot be predicted. The same goes for *spilt, learnt,* etc., despite the obvious pattern of the verb stem ending in *l* or *rn*: *burn* > *burnt*, but not *turn* > **turnt*.

#### Noah Webster

The reason why Americans write *spilled, learned* and *burned* and, unlike in Commonwealth nations, only use *spilt* and *burnt* as adjectives is because of the spelling reforms of Noah Webster, not because of some deep tendency in the language itself toward more regular forms. Curiously enough, he didn’t make a case for *builded*; the only problem he had with *built* was the *u*. He proposed instead to spell it *bild* and *bilt*, and did so — inconsistently — in his 1832 *History of the United States*:

> On a small isle, in a fresh water pond, within the large isle, he [*bilt*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044097034037;view=1up;seq=100;skin=mobile) a hut, and remained in it about six weeks. — Noah Webster, *History of the United States*, New Haven, 1832, 90.
>
> 360. First Shipping [*bilt*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044097034037;view=1up;seq=183;skin=mobile) in New England. The first attempt to *bild* water craft in New England, was in 1626. Ibid., 173.

In other passages, whether out of habit or through the intervention of a zealous typesetter, *build* and *built* launch a comeback:

> As the first colony which Columbus left was cut off, he sought a more convenient and healthful situation, marked out the plan of a town, erected a rampart, and [*built*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044097034037;view=1up;seq=85;skin=mobile) houses. Ibid., 75.

*Bild* and *bilt* — along with other proposed reforms like [*masheen, tung*](http://mentalfloss.com/article/53723/26-noah-webster%E2%80%99s-spelling-changes-didn%E2%80%99t-catch), and [*dawter*](http://mentalfloss.com/article/53723/26-noah-webster%E2%80%99s-spelling-changes-didn%E2%80%99t-catch) — never caught on.

#### Middle and Early Modern English

Though the Old English verb was quite rare,  *built* and *builded*,  in their varying form and orthography, were used concurrently in both Middle and Early Modern English. The prolific writer and monk John Lydgate of Bury seems to prefer *bilt*:

> Þis myȝti stronge cite..[*bilt*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=15284270&egdisplay=open&egs=15298371&egs=15288639) of lym and stoon. — John Lydgate, *Troy Book*, [1412–1420](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy_Book) (ms., Aug A.4, 1425), 5.545.

In the manuscript tradition of his *Siege of Thebes*, however, there is a variety of forms: *bilt, beld, bilded, bylde,* and even *ybylt* with the old Germanic perfective prefix (cf. Ger *geholfen* above, in English *ge-* > *y(e)* > Ø).

> A castel…Strong and myghty [*belt*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=15284270&egdisplay=open&egs=15298371&egs=15288639) [vrr. bilt, bildid, bylde, ybylt] vpon a roche. — John Lydgate, *Siege of Thebes*, [ca. 1420–22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Thebes_(poem)) 2269.

The two forms coexisted in Early Modern English:

> but he was dryuen thennes by brunmylda the quene and come in to almayn / and *builded* many abbayes… — William Caxton, trans., *Prolicionycion* [sic], 1482. EEBO
>
> for vpon thys mounte of sion was the temple of the Lorde *builded*. — Nicholas Udall, trans., Desiderius Erasmus, *Paraphrase of the New Testament* v. 1, 1548. EEBO
>
> who haue *builded* our schooles and vniuersities in england? — Robert Parsons, *A Temperate VVard-VVord*, 1599. EEBO
>
> cities: those which are seated neere rivers, for the most part are *builded* of stone; … — Robert Johnson, trans., Giovanni Botero, *Relation of the Most Famous Kingdomes and Common-wealths*, 1630. EEBO

> there was a certayne houszholder which planted a vynyarde, and hedged it roude aboute, and dygged a wyne presse in it, and *built* a tower, and let it out vnto huszbandmen, and wente in to a straunge countre: — Miles Coverdale, trans., *Biblia the Byble, that is, the holy Scrypture of the Olde and New Testament, faithfully translated in to Englyshe,* 1535. EEBO
>
> if one see but a house strongly and magnificently *built*, wisely and usefully contrived, gloriously and sumptuously adorn'd and furnish'd, though he as yet see no man appear in it, or about it, will he be such a fool as to say, it had no builder? for every house is *builded* by some man; but he that *built* all things is god, heb: iii:  — Clement Ellis, *The Folly of Atheism*, 1692. EEBO

While the KJV follows Coverdale in using *built* in [Mk 12.1](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/k/kjv/kjv-idx?type=DIV2&byte=4581041), Clement Ellis in following [Heb 3.4](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/k/kjv/kjv-idx?type=DIV2&byte=5281828) of the KJV in using *builded* and *built* in the same verse. The first use belongs to the author.

In the entire translation, the KJV uses [*builded*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/k/kjv/kjv-idx?type=simple&format=Long&q1=builded&restrict=All&size=First+100) 70 times, but [*built*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/k/kjv/kjv-idx?type=simple&format=Long&q1=built&restrict=All&size=First+100) 198.  This was likely enough to help preserve *builded* as a high register, archaic word suitable for poetic use far longer than any secular usage would warrant. Plus, one never knows when an extra syllable would add resonance or fill out the meter.

Comment: I added a sentence that should clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I still find the equation of “weak” and “regular” to be unnecessary and potentially misleading: *thought* and *bought* are weak past-tense forms in terms of Germanic historical linguistics, but obviously highly irregular.

Comment: The whole point of that discussion was to correct the OP’s understanding of _build_. Hybrids are “regular irregularities" where a j triggered an umlaut in the present tense but not preterite or participle, so there's a vowel change, but not like the strong verbs, but that really gets too far into the weeds for this question.

Answer (score 2):

I have only seen the abstract of the Nature article, but note that it says the authors proceeded by “tracking inflectional changes to 177 Old-English irregular verbs.” That methodology doesn't sound like it would be able to capture any information about verbs that started out regular and later became irregular. Knowing that irregular verbs tend to become regular over time doesn’t tell you that the number of irregular verbs in a language will go down over time (both statements may well be true; I'm just saying that the first doesn't logically imply the second).

As mentioned in the comments, there are various other examples of verbs that have become irregular. In some cases, there may be a phonological/phonetic motivation; in other cases, analogy is probably the cause.

The development of *-t* past-tense and past-participle forms is a bit complex, but they didn't just appear out of nowhere. In "[Irregular Verbs: Regularization and Ongoing Variability](https://books.google.com/books?id=leE5AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA22)", by Pam Peters (2009), I came across an interesting suggestion that the greater use of *-ed* forms in writing during certain historical periods may have been partly caused by the preference of certain prescriptive grammarians for regular forms:

> the *t*-form is a voiceless variant that goes back to Old English, and it is a well represented variant of many verbs in ME and EME, according to the *Oxford English Dictionary* (1989) records. British orthoepists and grammarians of the seventeenth and eighteenth centuries worked to regularize them all to *-ed,* in line with the linguistic trend of the times to disconnect norms of writing from vagaries of pronunciation (Gordon 1966). Data from historical corpora suggests that they were relatively successful in BrE until the later nineteenth century (Hundt 2009:14-15).

(p. 22, *Comparative Studies in Australian and New Zealand English: Grammar and beyond*)

Answer (score 1):

This was engraved on the Minneapolis Auditorium, erected 1927, demolished 1988.  The eagles that frame it were saved and now stand near the Minneapolis Convention Center that replaced the auditorium.

[image: Engraving on the outer wall of the Minneapolis Auditorium, erected 1927, demolished 1988]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).